# Orden del complemento circunstancial

Tags: gramática, sintaxis

¿Es una de las formas preferible o es indiferente?

1. Ser el primer gran grupo mediático que muestre **ante los pingüinos** verdadera profesionalidad y comprensión
2. Ser el primer gran grupo mediático que muestre verdadera profesionalidad y comprensión **ante los pingüinos**

Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para facilitar la lectura, y como gesto de amabilidad al lector, debe tenerse en cuenta que un complemento debería estar tanto más cerca de la palabra o estructura que modifica cuanto más relacionado esté con ella. Lo mejor que se puede hacer en este caso es mantener una estructura de cajas chinas:

> (i) Ser el primer gran grupo mediático que ([muestre {verdadera profesionalidad y comprensión}] ante los pingüinos).

Si se colocara "ante los pingüinos" entre "muestre" y "verdadera" se rompería esta estructura:

> (ii) Ser el primer gran grupo mediático que (muestre [ante los pingüinos] verdadera profesionalidad y comprensión).

Uno puede mostrar "verdadera profesionalidad y comprensión", pero no "muestra ante los pingüinos". Dicho de otra manera, "ante los pingüinos" modifica a "mostrar verdadera profesionalidad y comprensión", no simplemente a "mostrar". Por otra parte, "verdadera profesionalidad y comprensión" modifica a "mostrar", y no a "ante los pingüinos". En conclusión, con la estructura de (i) se tiene un complemento que modifica el verbo al que sigue y otro que modifica al conjunto del verbo y el primer complemento. Con la estructura de (ii) se tienen dos complementos donde ni el primero modifica el verbo al que sigue ni el segundo modifica al primero. La primera sigue un orden lógico mientras que la segunda anticipa una información que el lector no comprenderá hasta que no llegue al final de la oración. Dicho lo dicho, la primera estructura parece la más apropiada.

Ahora bien, existen otros casos donde otras máximas tienen más prioridad que la mencionada. Una de ellas es la relevancia:

> Ser el primer gran grupo mediático que muestre ante los pingüinos verdadera profesionalidad y comprensión, y ante el público, un gran sentido del humor.

En esta oración, es un gesto de respeto hacia lector introducir la frase "ante los pingüinos" antes de tiempo para que estos sepan que lo que se va a decir a continuación concierne exclusivamente a los pingüinos. La frase siguiente ("ante el público") informa al lector de que lo que sigue ya no se refiere a los pingüinos sino al público. Esto no pilla por sorpresa al lector: al ver una estructura con un orden diferente al estándar en la primera parte, se puede anticipar que existe una intención detrás de ello. Esto es, el lector sabe que "ante los pingüinos" es especialmente relevante, y la segunda parte será la que explique por qué: porque no solo se habla del trato hacia los pingüinos sino también del trato hacia el público.

Luego las estructuras que no siguen un orden canónico llaman la atención, provocan que el lector se pregunte qué puede haber motivado al escritor a no seguir un orden lógico, e interrumpen, en resumen, la lectura automática porque hacen saltar la "alarma" de detección de irregularidades que todo hablante posee aun sin ser consciente de ello. Cuando lo que hace saltar esta alarma es, por ejemplo, un fallo en la conjugación verbal o una falta de ortografía, la interrupción de la lectura automática distrae al lector y resta efectividad al texto. Cuando esto se hace de forma deliberada, se está usando un recurso literario conocido como hipérbaton que puede dotar a un texto, entre otras cosas, de contundencia.

La idea clave de toda esta verborrea es que no basta con colocar un elemento primero para llamar la atención sobre él, sino que debe colocarse en una posición inusual, sea al principio, en medio o al final. Debe tenerse en cuenta que colocar "ante los pingüinos" entre "muestre" y "verdadera" es desde luego inusual, que interrumpirá la lectura automática y que ello tendrá efectos en el lector. Es el escritor el que debe juzgar si estos efectos son deseados, si resultarán en una mayor contundencia o más bien en una pérdida de la eficacia comunicativa, y si con ello servirán para resaltar una determinada información o si tan solo distraerán al lector.

Answer (score 5):

Normalmente en español, los elementos con más importancia, énfasis o contraste van primero.

Así que, si lo que más quieres enfatizar es ante que/quién se ha mostrado algo, eso debe ir primero (como en tu primer ejemplo)

Si es lo que se ha mostrado que lleva más énfasis, lo normal sería poner eso just después del verbo (como en tu segundo ejemplo)

Y si quieres dar incluso más énfasis, cualquier elemento (¡incluso ambos!) puede preceder el verbo:

- ...que *ante los pingüinos* muestre...
- ...que *verdadera profesionalidad y comprensión* muestre...