# ¿Cómo redactar este título sin que suene ambiguo? "Recuperan una moto robada en el puente"

Tags: ambigüedad

Leyendo el diario me encontré con la noticia [*Recuperan una moto robada en el puente Belgrano*](https://www.datachaco.com/recuperan-una-moto-robada-el-puente-belgrano-n127930) y noté que de hecho la redacción cae en el mismo error que el título. No se entiende si:

- La moto fue robada sobre el puente, y luego fue recuperada.

o bien

- La moto fue robada antes, y al circular sobre el puente, fue recuperada.

El resto de la redacción tampoco aclara la duda de manera explícita. Se entiende luego, por el contexto, que la respuesta correcta es la segunda.

¿De qué forma se podría redactar este titular de manera concisa e inequívoca?

Comment: Yo creo que con mover el complemento ya se entendería unívocamente: _Recuperan en el puente una moto robada_.

Comment: Los diarios argentinos hacen eso todo el tiempo. Yo estoy *así* de coleccionar capturas de pantalla de esas ambigüedades.

Comment: ¿Cómo les parece "Moto robada recuperada en el puente"?

Comment: Bastante relacionado: [Orden del complemento circunstancial](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/16191/1674)

Answer (score 4):

En los comentarios se han sugerido un par de posibilidades, y por supuesto hay muchas más, porque esta información claramente se puede transmitir sin ambigüedad alguna, pero el meollo del asunto es que estamos hablando de un titular. Los titulares deben respetar ciertas convenciones, no sobrepasar cierta longitud, y concordar con el estilo general del medio donde se publican.

En el caso de este titular, se trata de un diario argentino; aquí diarios y portales de noticias tienen la costumbre de recurrir con frecuencia a la tercera persona del plural como sujeto genérico. La voz pasiva se usa poco y nada, y el orden de los complementos suele llevar a la ambigüedad, generalmente resuelta por el contexto y el sentido común, aunque no siempre (como en este caso).

Preservando ese estilo yo diría que el titular podría redactarse así:

> *Recuperan en el puente Belgrano una moto robada*

o bien con una convención también bastante utilizada, que sitúa el lugar del hecho como primer complemento:

> *Puente Belgrano: recuperan una moto robada*

Comment: Curiosa convención la de poner "lugar: hecho". ¿Es un recurso nuevo? En España nunca lo vi.

Comment: No es tan frecuente, pero aparece con lugares, eventos y personas, como si lo importante fuera establecer primero el contexto. «Colin Farrell: “Para ser felices tenemos que aceptar nuestras propias limitaciones”», «Notre Dame: las reliquias que se salvaron y las destruidas por el fuego».